# CRUD edit model data not showing in the table button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Guys I am stack for two days, I have two bootstrap models the first one is showing with outside button called submit, the other which the button is inside the table is not showing. Probably the problem could be the inclusion js library I am not sure and I don't have a lot of experience with that so i need your help below is my code! thanks in advance.

```
[![<div class="modal fade" id="editmodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editmodell" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="cdsViewformLabel">Informaçao do assunto</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">ID</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="idedit" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div> 
<!-- removed some code to show the textfields just to save space-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

below my table data and button

                  ?>
      <tbody class="ttdody">
        <tr>

          <td><?php echo $row\['ID'\];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row\['valor'\];?></td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs-view"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs-edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button>
            
          </td>        
        </tr>   
      </tbody>
      <?php
           
below is my js to display the modal
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btn-xs-edit').on('click', function () {
                $('#editmodel').modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script> 


<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--common script for all pages-->
  <script src="lib/common-scripts.js"></script>][1]][1]
```